# setExpectedResponseType() method in HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-rest

Below is the configuration of HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "rtpRequestChannel")
@Bean
public MessageHandler httResponseMessageHandler(MessageChannel rtpResponseChannel) {
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
            "http://localhost:8080/rtp");
    handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    handler.setOutputChannel(rtpResponseChannel);
    handler.setShouldTrack(true);
    handler.setStatsEnabled(true);
    return handler;
}
```

Below is the POST method in the REST controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rtp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<RTPResponse> persistRTP(@RequestBody RTPRequest request) {
    System.out.println("In post method " + request);
    if (request != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<RTPResponse>(new RTPResponse("12:12:2017", "Test", null, "100", "100"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<RTPResponse>(new RTPResponse("12:12:2017", "Dummy", null, "Dummy", "Dummy"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Below is the config of the service activator method:

```
@Override
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="rtpResponseChannel")
public void makeCall(ResponseEntity<RTPResponse> message) {
    System.out.println("Message: " + message.getBody());
    System.out.println(message.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

I am receiving null in the body of the ResponseEntity object. Which  configuration am I missing?

**Edit 1:**

When I use the `setExpectedResponseType()`, with the same controller configuration as above.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "rtpRequestPostOperationRequestChannel")
@Bean
public MessageHandler httResponseMessageHandler(MessageChannel rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel) {
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
            "http://localhost:8080/rtp");
    handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    handler.setOutputChannel(rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel);
    handler.setExpectedResponseType(RTPResponse.class);
    return handler;
}
```

The `RTPResponse` object is not wrapped in the `ResponseEntity`.

I get the error as below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method makeCall(rtp.model.RTPResponse) cannot be found on rtp.RTPRequestServiceClient type
```

**Edit 2:**

In other words, what configuration should I use on the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` to get hold of the message object so that I have the extracted body in the message payload and all the headers to the `MessageHeaders`, including status.

I tried using `GenericMessage` being passed to the `setExpectedResponseType` method of `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` class.

But it gave me the error as below which is understandable:

`Can not construct instance of org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you said yourself - `setExpectedResponseType()`.

You really miss exactly this configuration.

In that case the `body` of response entity is empty:

```
private class ResponseEntityResponseExtractor<T> implements ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<T>> {

    @Nullable
    private final HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T> delegate;

    public ResponseEntityResponseExtractor(@Nullable Type responseType) {
        if (responseType != null && Void.class != responseType) {
            this.delegate = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<>(responseType, getMessageConverters(), logger);
        }
        else {
            this.delegate = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<T> extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (this.delegate != null) {
            T body = this.delegate.extractData(response);
            return ResponseEntity.status(response.getRawStatusCode()).headers(response.getHeaders()).body(body);
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(response.getRawStatusCode()).headers(response.getHeaders()).build();
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't like to provide a `Class<?>` for that option, you can consider to use:

```
/**
 * Specify the {@link Expression} to determine the type for the expected response
 * The returned value of the expression could be an instance of {@link Class} or
 * {@link String} representing a fully qualified class name.
 * @param expectedResponseTypeExpression The expected response type expression.
 * Also see {@link #setExpectedResponseType}
 */
public void setExpectedResponseTypeExpression(Expression expectedResponseTypeExpression) {
```

instead. In this case you really can resolve the target expected response type against a `requestMessage` and also get access to the whole `BeanFactory` for some other beans calls.

Comment: Hello Artem, I added the edit to explain the issue I am facing with `setExpectedResponseType`

Comment: Oh! I see. You want to have `ResponseEntity<RTPResponse>` as a method argument, but we don't support that. You need a `Message<RTPResponse>` instead. there is no reason in the `ResponseEntity` since we extract its `body` to a `payload` and copy all the headers to the `MessageHeaders`, including `status`.

Comment: Sorry Artem, I did not understand what you meant by " You need a `Message<RTPResponse>` instead" in your comment above. Adding the query as Edit 2.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn’t clear. Your service method `makeCall()` has to be changed to accept `Message<RTPTesponse>` instead of current `ResponseEntity`. The `HttpReeuestExecutionMessageHandler` still has to be configured with the `setExpectedResponseType()`. Let me know if that is not clear yet.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I figured out from your last comment when I read it closely. Now it works. I have overloaded method in the Controller class. One to return RTPResponse and the other one returns ResponseEntity for web usage.